# Cannot return value from a function in other file

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I'm building a scraper to get sizes of some shoes I want to buy. I have a `main` file that pass the `sku` to a second file who is in charge of getting the sizes and return them to the main file. The issue I'm having is that I can't get the return values in the main file, but I can `console.log()` them out. Here's an example code:

**File A:**

```js
const sizes = require('./fileb.js');

function getSizes()  {
    console.log(sizes.getAvailableSizes("T8528002"))
}

(async function() {
    await getSizes()
})();
```

**File B:**

```js
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const cheerio = require("cheerio");

let size = {};
var sizeList = []

size.getAvailableSizes = async (sku) => {
    await fetch(`https://www.footlocker.com/en/product/~/${sku}.html`, {
        // Parameters
    })
    .then((res) => res.text())
    .then((body) => {
      const $ = cheerio.load(body);

      $(".ProductSize-group div")
        .not(".c-form-field--disabled")
        .each((i, element) => {
          sizeList.push($(element).text().replace(/^0+/, "").replace(".0", ""));
        });

        console.log(sizeList)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
    });

    return sizeList
};

module.exports = size;
```

And here is my output:

```
➜  footsites node filea
Promise { <pending> }
[ '10', '10.5' ]
➜  footsites
```

How can I get the value to be returned properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sizes.getAvailableSizes("T8528002")` returns a promise, so logging that directly will be logging a promise. Instead, you can do the logging after you `await` the promise:

```js
const sizes = require('./fileb.js');

function getSizes()  {
    return sizes.getAvailableSizes("T8528002");
}

(async function() {
    console.log(await getSizes());
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

An `async` function always returns a `promise` and we need to use `.then()` block and get our data. In your case, the Promise is returned but has not been handled yet.

I think the Pending Promise which is returned from `fileb`  should not just be consoled logged but first data should be fetched and then used further.

Try modifying your `filea` with this code and see how it reacts :)

```
const sizes = require('./fileb.js');

sizes.getAvailableSizes("T8528002")).then(data=>console.log(data));
```

Comment: got it, thank you! do i need to use it on filea or fileb? :/

Comment: @MikeHenriquez Don't forget you can accept/check the answer that works for you.

Comment: Once you are returning size info from fileb... I don't feel we need another async function in filea  again. We can simply get our data using function getSizes()  {
sizes.getAvailableSizes("T8528002").then(data=>console.log(data));
}

Comment: Because if you do (async function() {
    console.log(await getSizes());
})();   When will you use your data then... :)